# Why does *= resolve after +

Tags: c#

Is there ever any cuircumstance where the following algorithms are **not** equal?

```
int var1 = 2;
int var2 = 5;
int var3 = 7;

// Scenario 1
var1 *= var2 + var3; // <-- 24

// Scenario 2
var1 = 2;
var1 *= (var2 + var3); // <-- 24
```

The reason I ask is because [msdn site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/6a71f45d.aspx) states the following:

> These operators have **higher precedence** than the next section and lower precedence than the previous section.

However, from my testing, it seems that this is never the case? And that even without the brackets, it seems to resolve as if it had brackets.

I would of thought that the algorithms would be equal to:

```
// Scenario 1
var1 = var1 * var2 + var3; // <-- 17

//Scenario 2
var1 = var1 * (var2 + var3); // <-- 24
```

---

So what is meant by the msdn site and in what cases is their statement true?

**C# fiddle for testing:**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yt5ZBO

Comment: Binary operator `*=` has lower precedence than the binary operator `+`.

Comment: @zerkms so the msdn site is wrong? or am I missunderstanding something here?

Comment: It is not wrong. Why is it?

Comment: The reason for your confusion is because the section you are looking at is the ***Arithmetic Overflow*** section, not the ***Additive Operators*** section.  You are simply misreading the documentation.

Comment: @DavidL yes - you are correct. My mistake - thankyou

Comment: I'd say the MSDN documentation is slightly wrong because it says the Assignment and Lambda operators "have higher precedence than the next section" but the next section is not part of the list of operators. There should be no next section; that heading should instead be a footnote. The documentation implies that Assignment and Lambda operators have higher precedence than Arithmetic Overflow (whatever that would mean, if it made sense).

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou 100% agree and not at all friendly to tired eyes & mind.

Comment: @DavidL I have submitted feedback to the msdn doc: I think this page needs to be placed into a table like previous versions, because Arithmetic Overflow is not an operator and should be more clearly a foot note as previous versions. 

In current form I think it is easy to mistake that Assignment operators take precedence over (+,-,*,/) especailly because the first sentence under 'Assignment and Lambda Operators' states 'higher precedence than the next section' when technically there is no operator which follows.

As mistaken by myself here: http://stackoverflow.com/.... etc.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou See comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So what is meant by the msdn site and in what cases is their statement true?

It means exactly what it states: the sections are ordered from higher to lower precedence.

In their list `*=` operator (it's a single operator and its precedence has no relations with the precedence of either `=` or `*`) has lower precedence than the binary `+` operator.

So `+` is evaluated first.

Comment: I have made a mistake, I was looking at the **Arithmetic Overflow** section, not the **Additive Operators** section. *whoops*

Answer (score 0):

> These operators have higher precedence than the next section (+, -, *, /)

You have added the `(+, -, *, /)` to this quote (incorrectly), what it actually says is:

> These operators have higher precedence than the next section and lower precedence than the previous section.

`+` is in the *previous* section, so it has higher precedence.

Comment: oh whoops - haha I did mess that quote up